# How to improve system security? Software, books what do you recommend?

Tags: security

as per object what do you recommend to improve the security of a workstation?
What guides \ books, websites, browser extensions and even antivirus?

Thank you all.

Comment: This question is very open-ended, and not really answerable as per the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask). Maybe try a discussion forum, and research on from there.

Comment: Try a couple episodes of the [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/) from the Ubuntu Security Team for a good orientation. AskUbuntu is the wrong place to *start* your research. It's good place to ask specific questions once you have already done a lot of learning.

Comment: whatever you read on this... antivirus is not the answer. It creates even more security issues as those do not work on linux and do send and receive data from over the web.   @ArturMeinild I am not too sure the answer listing what actually to do or not to do is open ended. There is a limited amount of things to do. But ... I also know this has been answered before ... by me :D

Comment: I'm sure of that!  If you can find a duplicate, I can support that. I just found the question as it stands opinion-based, since it's not very specific and more a loose recommendation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Brainstorming:

- You try to utilize Linux as a workstation? You are safer than the rest automatically by its nature and its spare usage by the people. Attackers/hackers are focusing on the great majority of operation systems, i.e. Windows, MacOS, Android, iOS.
- Activate the screensaver after minutes of inactivity
- Linux doesn't need anti-virus software - never used one in profession and private. Has something to do, among other things, with the strict separation of kernel and user space. So when you click on any email attachment it does not reach the kernel space provided your email client program is not running by root.
- Be careful of what you install on your workstation. When you install any server software there (e.g ssh server), of course, you could be open to any breach if you don't know what happens under the hood. Do not stay with the default settings/configuration, so restrain it.
- Book recommendation: *How Linux Works* by Brian Ward